# Javascript html adding extra lines of text with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I basically have a main title `<h1>` and i want it to add a new extra line picked from my array so that the line is added to the end of `<p1>`. Right now, i seem to be able to add a string under my title when i click the title. But how can i make it so that the string is added at the end of `<p1>`. `<p1>` is suppose to be the first line of the story and every time i click on `<h1>` a extra line of the story will be added.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
#canvas{
                margin: 5px;
                padding 5px;
                background: green;
                border: 1px solid black;
                }
</style>
<script>
    var maFonction=function(elem,event,couleur) {
        elem.style.color=couleur;
    }

    var insertText=function( text) {
        var elem=text;
        elem.innerHTML+=text;
    }

    var newtable=new Array();
    newtable[0]="Salut";
    newtable[1]="Bye";
    newtable[2]="Hey";

    var clickSurSection2 = function(newtable,element) {
        for(var i=0;i<newtable.length;i++){
            element.innerHTML += "<br>Nouveau mot: "+ newtable[i];
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
<h1 onmouseover="maFonction(this,event,'red');" onmouseout="maFonction(this,event,'blue');" onclick="clickSurSection2(newtable,this);">Cliquez moi pour en savoir plus</h1>

<p1>Un jeune garcon vivait dans une petite village dans la montagne.</br></p1>


<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your story

elements into a div, and then add the new lines at the end:

```
<div id="story">
<p1>Un jeune garcon vivait dans une petite village dans la montagne.</p1>
</div>
```

Then, script would be:

```
document.getElementById("story").innerHTML += "<br>Nouveau mot: "+ newtable[line];
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtUdV/)

Answer (score 0):

```
onmouseout="maFonction(this,event,'blue');"
```

The problem comes from "this".

You are calling maFonction() with `this` as parameter. `this` represent `h1` in your case. So it adds the text at the end of `h1`, and you have the feeling it is added to the beginning of `p1`

So you should give an ID to `p1` like this :

```
<p1 id="story"> </p1>
```

And then, call your function from `h1` like this :

```
<h1 onmouseover="maFonction(document.getElementById('story'),event,'red');" onmouseout="maFonction(document.getElementById('story'),event,'blue');" onclick="clickSurSection2(newtable,this);">Cliquez moi pour en savoir plus</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/96v6h/

```
<body>

<h1 onmouseover="maFonction(this,event,'red');" onmouseout="maFonction(this,event,'blue');" onclick="clickSurSection2(newtable,this);">Cliquez moi pour en savoir plus </h1>

    <p1>Un jeune garcon vivait dans une petite village dans la montagne.</p1>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
    <script>
        var maFonction = function(elem, event, couleur) {
            elem.style.color = couleur;
        }
        var insertText = function(text) {
            var elem = text;
            elem.innerHTML += text;
        }
        var newtable = new Array();
        newtable[0] = "Salut";
        newtable[1] = "Bye";
        newtable[2] = "Hey";
        var clickSurSection2 = function(newtable, element) {
            for (var i = 0; i < newtable.length; i++) {
                element.innerHTML += "Nouveau mot: " + newtable[i] + " ";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

You should remove the line breaks (`<br>`). Working fiddle is above. Also you were missing a semicolon in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Give p1 an id and use getElementById to get the p1 element in clickSurSection2 function amd append it with the text

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understud your question, but try replacing this function with yours:

```
var clickSurSection2 = function(newtable) {

    var newElement = document.createElement("P");
    var pElement = document.getElementById("myId");
    pElement.parentNode.insertBefore(element, pElement.nextSibling);

    for(var i=0;i<newtable.length;i++){
        element.innerHTML += "<br>Nouveau mot: "+ newtable[i];
    }
}
```

and change your

```
<p1>
```

to

```
<p1 id="myId">
```

and

```
<h1 onclick="clickSurSection2(newtable,this);">
```

to

```
<h1 onclick="clickSurSection2(newtable);">
```